# Nginx does not read my config file

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx on Mac, I installed it using Homebrew, and it used to work fine until this morning. Now, after a reboot, it doesn't read my `nginx.conf` (from `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) anymore and loads its default `index.html` from `/usr/local/var/www`. If I force pass the config file explicitly using -c switch (`sudo nginx -c /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`), nginx runs fine. Yesterday, I ran (python's) `SimpleHTTPServer` to serve a file and test something, then quit, and shut down. `SimpleHTTPServer` is not running anymore, I just ran it a couple of times yesterday. I don't know if the issue is related to that, but just in case. `lsof` does not show any process running on ports 80 or 443 except nginx.

**Update:**

In my `nginx.conf`, I serve files from different directories in a specified order (some directories are sym-linked):

```
location ~ ^/(js/|css/|img/|audio/|fonts/|files/|images/|video/) {
          root /Users/me/development/myCompany;
          try_files /staticFrontend/$uri /angularjsSPA/develop/$uri =404;
        }
```

Again `sudo nginx -c /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` works fine, but `sudo nginx` does not.

Comment: Is the default configuration file in /usr/local… rather than /etc/nginx or someplace else? Does OS X have a "trace system calls made by this program?" When I run `strace nginx` on my Linux machine I get `open("/etc/nginx/nginx.conf", O_RDONLY) = 3` which tells me where the default configuration file llives.

Comment: @msw yes, the default path for nginx and its configuration files is different on OS X if you install nginx using **homebrew**.

Comment: I had a similar issue on windows nginx. Turns out that I had multiple copies of nginx running (running with an older config). If you have this issue on windows check task manager for other nginx instances.

Answer (score 3):

This would better be a comment, however, I've got not enough reputation to do so:

- Could you clarify your problem? You wrote, that nginx is serving content from `/usr/local/var/www`. What do you expect instead? Did you specify a different folder? If so, which one, and in which config did you do this?
- Normally, `nginx.conf` is used to specify general configuration directives.
- Server blocks are normally specified in configs located in `sites-available/`, and symlinked from there to `sites-enabled/`. Upon startup, nginx reads these configs, where you would specify a different folder than `/usr/local/var/www` for example.

Comment: In my config file, I serve files from different directories (some of them are symlinked):